# Cannot colour in my graph like I want

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, color

So I tried

```
SyrianGovernment = {"Al-Safira"};
FSA = {"Atarib"}; 
ISIS = {"Al-Bab","Dayr Hafir","Jarabulus", "Manbij"}; 
YPG = {"Afrin","Ayn Al-Arab"}; 
Contested = {"South Mount Simeon", "North Mount Simeon", "Aleppo", "Azaz"};

vs = Join @@ MapThread[Thread[#1 -> #2] &, {{SyrianGovernment, FSA, ISIS, YPG}, 
                                            {Red, Green, Black, Yellow, Gray}}];
mm = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {65, 65}];

AdjacencyGraph[mm, VertexSize -> 0.4, VertexStyle -> vs]
```

I'm sure you can see what I'm trying to do here (I'm trying to colour the vertices or nodes of a `Graph`). I'm trying to colour my `Graph` four colours depending on what *group* they're in. I'd also like to know if I can program it such that nodes which I do not name can be coloured a certain colour as *the rest*.

This works:

```
SyrianGovernment = {"Al-Safira", "Al-Nabk", "Qatana", "Al-Qutayfah", "Al-Tall","Yabrud", "Zabadani", "Izra", "Al-Sanamayn"};FSA = {"Atarib", "South Mount Simeon", "Abu Kamal", "Mayadin"};ISIS = {"Al-Bab", "Dayr Hafir", "Jarabulus", "Manbij"};YPG = {"Afrin", "Ayn Al-Arab"};Contested = {"South Mount Simeon", "North Mount Simeon", "Aleppo","Azaz", "Darayya", "Duma", "Qudsaya", "Markaz Rif Dimashq","Daraa", "Deir ez-Zor"};

SeedRandom@5;
list = Flatten[{SyrianGovernment, FSA, ISIS, YPG, Contested}, 1];
vs = Flatten[MapThread[Thread[Rule[#1, #2]] &, {{_, SyrianGovernment, FSA, ISIS,YPG}, {Gray, Red, Green, Black, Yellow}}], 1];
g = Graph[(DirectedEdge @@@ DeleteDuplicates@RandomChoice[list, {65, 2}]), VertexSize -> .5,VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20, VertexStyle -> vs]
```

But when I add say `"Hama"` to `SyrianGovernment` (or anything more for that matter), the graphic disappears.

So this doesn't work:

```
SyrianGovernment = {"Al-Safira", "Al-Nabk", "Qatana", "Al-Qutayfah", "Al-Tall","Yabrud", "Zabadani", "Izra", "Al-Sanamayn","Hama"};FSA = {"Atarib", "South Mount Simeon", "Abu Kamal", "Mayadin"};ISIS = {"Al-Bab", "Dayr Hafir", "Jarabulus", "Manbij"};YPG = {"Afrin", "Ayn Al-Arab"};Contested = {"South Mount Simeon", "North Mount Simeon", "Aleppo","Azaz", "Darayya", "Duma", "Qudsaya", "Markaz Rif Dimashq","Daraa", "Deir ez-Zor"};

SeedRandom@5;
list = Flatten[{SyrianGovernment, FSA, ISIS, YPG, Contested}, 1];
vs = Flatten[MapThread[Thread[Rule[#1, #2]] &, {{_, SyrianGovernment, FSA, ISIS,YPG}, {Gray, Red, Green, Black, Yellow}}], 1];
g = Graph[(DirectedEdge @@@ DeleteDuplicates@RandomChoice[list, {65, 2}]), VertexSize -> .5,VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20, VertexStyle -> vs]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem was that by doing:

```
adjg = AdjacencyGraph[RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {20, 20}]];
```

you have `VertexCount@adjg` equal to `20` while you only have `12` vertices:

```
{"Al-Safira", "Atarib", "Al-Bab", "Dayr Hafir", "Jarabulus", "Manbij", "Afrin", 
 "Ayn Al-Arab", "South Mount Simeon", "North Mount Simeon", "Aleppo", "Azaz"}
```

Thus, if you want a randomly distributed `Graph` I would propose the following:

```
SyrianGovernment = {"Al-Safira", "Al-Nabk", "Qatana", "Al-Qutayfah", "Al-Tall", "Yabrud", "Zabadani", "Izra", "Al-Sanamayn", "Hama"}; 
FSA = {"Atarib", "South Mount Simeon", "Abu Kamal", "Mayadin"};
ISIS = {"Al-Bab", "Dayr Hafir", "Jarabulus", "Manbij"};
YPG = {"Afrin", "Ayn Al-Arab"};
Contested = {"South Mount Simeon", "North Mount Simeon", "Aleppo", "Azaz", "Darayya", "Duma", "Qudsaya", "Markaz Rif Dimashq", "Daraa", "Deir ez-Zor"};
SeedRandom@5;
possibleCities = {SyrianGovernment, FSA, ISIS, YPG, Contested};
list = DeleteDuplicates@RandomChoice[Flatten[possibleCities, 1], {65, 2}];
cities = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@list;
col = (First /@ (First@Position[possibleCities, #] & /@ cities)) /. 
  {1 -> Green, 2 -> Black, 3 -> Yellow, 4 -> Red, _?IntegerQ -> Gray};
vs = Rule @@@ Thread[{cities, col}];
Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ list, VertexSize -> .5, VertexLabels -> "Name",
  ImagePadding -> 20, VertexStyle -> vs]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

- Note that your requirement:

  > I'd also like to know if I can program it such that nodes which I do not name can be coloured a certain colour as 'the rest'.

  is fulfilled by `_?IntegerQ -> Gray` where *any integer*, `_?IntegerQ`, is associated with `Gray`. Since it is placed in the end, it does not overwrite the form `Rule`s.
- Note also that `EdgeCount@g` is not equal to `65` because of the `DeleteDuplicates` in order prevent the following error due the repetitiveness of `RandomChoice`:

  > Graph::supp: Mixed graphs and multigraphs are not supported.

  At last, note that all the cities are not present because of the randomness of `RandomChoice`.

Comment: That worked, but once I got to 30 nodes the graphic disappears. Help?

Comment: @user3482534 did you add colours accordingly with nodes? You can edit your question with your 30 nodes if you want.

Comment: I edited as you asked.

Comment: @user3482534 Should work like a charm now :)

Answer (score 1):

You are associating 5 colors to 4 lists in `vs` (you forgot `Contested`), and I don't understand the use of `Join`. Try with this code: it works fine for me:

```
SyrianGovernment = {"Al-Safira"};
FSA = {"Atarib"};
ISIS = {"Al-Bab", "Dayr Hafir", "Jarabulus", "Manbij"};
YPG = {"Afrin", "Ayn Al-Arab"};
Contested = {"South Mount Simeon", "North Mount Simeon", "Aleppo", 
   "Azaz"};
vs = MapThread[
   Thread[#1 -> #2] &, {{SyrianGovernment, FSA, ISIS, YPG, 
     Contested}, {Red, Green, Black, Yellow, Gray}}];
mm = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {65, 65}];
AdjacencyGraph[mm, VertexSize -> 0.4, VertexStyle -> vs]
```

Hope it helps.